# Move subsite programmatically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell

I have to move a subsite in a site collection to a new site in the root level. I want to achieve this through powershell. The "Content and Structure" page located at /_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx works perfectly for moving the site. I just want to do the same thing via powershell.
I tried Export/Import-SPWeb, but it takes a lot of time while the process in the content and structure moves the site in less than a minute.

Does someone know what is the back-end SharePoint Object Model method called behind the scenes of "Content and Structure" page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this script

```
 $web=Get-SpWeb "http://subsiteurl"
 $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates=$true
 $web.ServerRelativeUrl="/newRelativeURL/"
 $web.Update()
 $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates=$false
```

Comment: You may have to go update various hyperlinks such as in the quick launch (not a huge deal), but another weird one was in Site Settings for Access requests and invitations where it didn't update that link, but all the other one's it did.